# git and merge. Checkout one directory from one branch into another

Tags: git, github

I have e.g. two branches.  master and development.  I created a branch called master_fix.

I have a directory that is in both the master and development branch.  In the master_fix branch that I created, I only want to update one folder from the development branch.  How do I do that?

E.g. all branches have folderA but in different stages.  I want to use only folderA from development branch and update folderA in master_fix branch.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to update your working tree with `development`'s version of `folder1`, make sure you are in the `master_fix` branch, and run:

```
$ git checkout development -- folder1
```

You would then have to add and commit that change if you want it to stay on the `master_fix` branch.